# How to sign out of all devices (includes Chrome) using Google service?

Tags: google-chrome

I am stuck with my laptop. Sometimes, the display would be turned on/off multiple times automatically. I have NOTHING to do except waiting about 30 minutes later.

If I tried to shut down, the power button should be `locked`, too. I don't know why. `Locked` means: I cannot use it to start (it did nothing while I pressed it). But I can try to do that again after 30 mins.

In that case, if I cannot start my PC, I cannot clear my history (and passwords...) in the Chrome. So, I want to signout the account from another device (another PC...).

Here is the button I want to press:

[image: 1]

I want to sign out before I bring it for guarantee.

How can I do that?

Comment: This is off-topic, because it does not seem to be about programming.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Gmail (from any device) and login with your user.
2. In the bottom right corner, click Details and then Sign out all other web sessions.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to look for it so hard but I cannot see it anywhere

Comment: This "details" thing is indeed very small. I suggest that you press ctrl+f in order to search in page, and search for "details", then I'm sure you will find it